# JSON Attribute Best Practice

Tags: javascript, json

Usually, what I see is `{"attribute":241241}`

but writting this does exactly the same thing : `{attribute:241241}`.

Is  `{attribute:241241}` considered bad practice and should be avoided or not?

Comment: The second isn't really valid json.  It's a valid javascript object literal though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{attribute:241241}` does not validate using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), so yes, it is bad practice and should be avoided.

Further, if you look at the JSON spec at [json.org](http://json.org/), you will find that for objects the first value is always a string (indicated by double quotes).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing JSON with Object literal syntax, in Javascript doing

```
var o = {
    "attribute":241241
};
```

is **not** JSON, but object literal. And yes, the quotes are useless there.

Answer (score 1):

As per the specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), the names in name/value pairs must be of type `string`.

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs,
> where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean,
> null, object, or array.

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON specification](http://json.org/) requires that keys be quoted, so the second form isn't valid JSON.

As Snakes and Coffee noted, it is a valid Javascript object literal (on which JSON is based), and some JSON parsers will accept it anyway.  So it may work in some cases, but sooner or later you'll run into a perfectly functional JSON parser that rejects your non-quoted keys because they aren't valid per the spec.

Comment: I have never heard of JSON parser accepting unquoted keys, note that calling `eval()` is not JSON parsing, it would actually run the input as javascript code